# Check if application is not running

Tags: installation, wix, wix3.6

I am developing a WiX installer (I am very new to this) and want to implement a method (like launch condition) which check if a particular application is running or not. If it's running then a warning message will popup displaying close the application message. I want this check before the welcome screen.

How can I implement this? Some working example will really help me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Windows Installer already has a [FilesInUse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and RMFilesInUse ([Restart Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372466%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) support.  Does this not meet your needs?    With these patterns you'll get a dialog telling the user that they need to exit a program or risk needing a reboot.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done only through a custom action. Here is a tutorial for a C++ DLL native custom action: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1747/MSI-Custom-Action-DLL

Your custom action can perform the check and then show a message to the user if necessary. It 
can return 0 to continue the installation or [1602](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to stop.

To show the message before Welcome dialog, you can try scheduling your custom action right after CostFinalize action in InstallUISequence.